# Cons and pros of using Base64 encode and decode image in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, base64

This is block of code I used for convert from Image into Base64:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.image);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String imgStr =Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But I know we also can convert image into Binary data.
So just want to know the cons and pros of using Base64 encode image in Android. Should I use Base64 or Binary data to transfer image through message.

Comment: message of gcm is limited you can not send all images and even sending is not good practise

Comment: So can you give me some way we can do it instead?

Comment: You can use xmpp for chat.

Answer (score 1):

You should not send images through gcm server. It was not designed for that at all. You should be sending links, and other information, which is then used to get the data from a server after being received on the client (server-> client pushes).

Base64 is often used when transferring binary data as a string, which is stupid in this case because it increases the size of the data needing transfered, and you could easily do a POST to a server with the binary data directly.

Comment: Could you provide some lines of code for me to do that (convert from images to binary data)

Comment: The images will be in binary data after you obtain them from a camera intent, or gallery picker intent. http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: I totally know how does it work but just one more question: we can store that binary data by store values from extras.get("data");, is it right?

Comment: Yes... But definitely not recommended. Bundles are very inefficient for storing large amounts of data. After you take/pick the image, you should stream it directly from the filesystem to a server for remote storage.